# University exercise - How to bridge wireless network

Tags: cisco, wireless, dhcp, ping, dns

We are currently working on a university exercise and are stumped when it comes to replicating this network, what we are trying to achieve is wireless clients to obtain DHCP address's from a W2k12r2 server through a Wireless Access Points, below is our setup

```
    WAP
    WAP4410N
    IP 200.10.1.5
    Subnet 255.255.255.192
    Gateway 200.10.1.1

    RRAS/DHCP Server
    IP 200.10.1.1
    Subnet 255.255.255.192
    No Gateway set

    Client**-----**WAP**-----**RRAS/DHCP Server
```

We are configuring the WAP to static connect to the wireless adapter on the lab server and then also accept clients on a seperate SSID to connect and obtain a DHCP lease from the RRAS/DHCP Server.

We are NOT able to physically connect the WAP and the server through a switch, so one SSID is a point to point manually configured as above and the other will be a client network. So all connections occur wirelessly

The two SSID's have segmentation disabled

We have two interfaces on our RRAS server one WAN and one LAN, we are using RIP to extend from a Cisco Router

```
    Client**--**WAP**--**RRAS--CISCO--RRAS--Client(Physically wired)
```

When we try to ping the Cisco router and other WAN/LAN networks we can ping successfully, however once a client connects to the WAP, DHCP is not being passed through(Yes its in the DHCP bindings) and when we do manually configure the client we CAN ping the WAP and the RRAS/DHCP server on 200.10.1.1 but no further while the WAP somehow can

We do not have firewalls enabled and there are currently no ACL on the Firewall/Cisco Router

It feels like it is something to do with the client not understanding the correct gateway however when manually assigning it to either 200.10.1.1 OR 200.10.1.5 it makes no difference in the ability to ping

Can anyone help?

Comment: Sadly, school work is off topic here.